# Size of a Canvas in a Surfaceview against real screen resolution

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas

I am trying to use the SurfaceView and the Canvas to make some draws, in my 480x800 phone, but I do not understand how this is managed, because when I display canvas size, it show 320x533 ( while my screen is 480x800 )

I tryied to use setFixedSize() on the getHolder to reset the canvas resolution, seems to work fine, but is it a correct way to do such resize ?

Another trouble is getting the touch event coordinates, while my canvas seem to be resized, to touch events are still matched against a 320x533 screen, how can I change that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is running in compatibility mode. You must either target the proper API level or declare in your manifest that you support multiple densities.

Comment: Thanx, I have added the <supports-screens> and all is fine now.